# Several JDK on one machine

Tags: java

I run Ubuntu with standar java that come with it (1.7). Now I need to test some applications using java 1.4. How to install both java on the same machine? I will also need this JDK for NetBeans IDE.

UPD.
I have downloaded j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin file and executed it.
Output:

```
Unpacking...
tail: cannot open ‘+466’ for reading: No such file or directory
Checksumming...
1
The download file appears to be corrupted.  Please refer
to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation
Instructions on the download page for more information.
Please do not attempt to install this archive file.
```

UPD

I have changed j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin files line

```
tail +466 $0 > $outname
```

to

```
tail -n +466 $0 > $outname
```

But still have error below:

```
Checksumming...
    1
    The download file appears to be corrupted.  Please refer
    to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation
    Instructions on the download page for more information.
    Please do not attempt to install this archive file.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place JDK 1.4 in a `programs` folder in your home directory, something like this for example:

```
/home/vico/programs/jdk1.4.x_xx
```

Then, you can add it to your path variable like this, so that bash and netbeans find this version of java first:

```
export PATH="/home/vico/programs/jdk1.4.x_xx/bin:$PATH"
```

If you are in the habit of doing this frequently, you can add the `PATH` modifier to your `~/.profile` file.

Of course, you can explicitly tell netbeans what version of java to use by editing this line in your `etc/netbeans.conf` file:

```
#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/your/jdk"
```

And similarly, the `-vm` option in `eclipse.ini` for the Eclipse IDE:

```
-vm
/path/to/your/java_executable
```

**EDIT**

`tar.gz` isn't available on [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html) for the ancient version you are trying to install (1.4.x_xx). Firstly, make the `j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin` file executable by doing this:

```
chmod u+x j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin
```

Then first try running the executable without root like this:

```
./j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin
```

Hopefully, it should allow you a local installation in your ~/ (home directory). If it fails, however, then try sudo:

```
sudo ./j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940448/how-to-install-j2sdk-1-4-2-on-64bit-linux) SO link for more details.

Comment: But how to install in /home/vico/programs/jdk1.4.x_xx directory? Just download tar.gz and extract?

Comment: Yup, just extract the tar.gz to that folder structure! And then use bash to edit `PATH` variable or start netbeans.

Comment: I run 64 bit ubuntu and have downloaded several installations  j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-i586-rpm.bin, j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64.bin,
 j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin. After execution all of them reported error: Unpacking...
tail: cannot open ‘+466’ for reading: No such file or directory
Checksumming...

Comment: Don't download/run anything containing the word `RPM` on ubuntu, just download the `DEB` or better still, the `tar.gz` like I said. `RPM`s are for the Fedora/RHEL world, they have nothing to do with us.

Comment: There are only two options for linux in official oracle site - rpm and rpm.bin . How to install java for ubuntu in this case then?

Comment: @vico See my updated answer for that (after the **EDIT** in bold).

Comment: What happened? Did you try installing the `j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin`?

Comment: I have executed file and described it in message body and have fixed tail problem, but still have Checksumming error

Comment: DON'T change any lines in the Java installation file (that's the reason the checksum validation is failing). Since original message is complaining as `cannot open ‘+466’ for reading`, looks like it is not having proper read rights to those files, just give it the read rights as follows: `chmod u+x j2sdk-1_4_2_04-linux-ia64-rpm.bin`.

Comment: I tried this way, but this not helps. In this case I have both errors